# regarding mex endpoints in wcf

Tags: wcf

here is one sample of mex endpoints

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

but i have seen people write mex endpoints like

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/mex"
                      binding="mexTcpBinding"
                      contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

so tell me why and when one should write mex endpoint like above one.
just compare my two endpoints and see the difference that first one address attribute has
the word called "mex" but second one has url.

so my question is "when people has to give a url to address attribute of mex endpoints?".

Another question is "Does mex address url always should have /mex word at the end of url?".
if i give url like `net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/ or net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer` without mex word then service will not be discoverable?

what is the significiant of /mex word??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first one will expose metadata over http and second one will do it over the TCP . It is used to support the platforms, **WCF is made for supporting multiple platform.**

you can make any url to expose metadata. it is not necessary to follow the convention above.
mex is just more good practice to make it metadata just same like url+mex .

here is an url which will give an overview

http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/27/wcf-metadata/

Comment: if i omit the first mex endpoint then just tell me how any asp.net apps can create proxy for the wcf service. it will be possible or not to create proxy from asp.net web apps when we host service in iis with mexTcpBinding.

Comment: you can extract metadata even if http mex endpoint is not supported. svcutil.exe will do it for you . try it and let me know